# Vivado Design Suite Reed-Solomon Decoder

Tags: reed-solomon

in the description of [Reed-Solomon Decoder v9.0](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/rs_decoder/v9_0/pg107-rs-decoder.pdf) p 20

> **ERR_CNT Element**
>
> The ERR_CNT element gives the number of errors, erasures, and
> punctures that were corrected. The width of the element depends on the
> input parameters n and k. The width is equal to the number of binary
> bits required to represent (n-k). If n-k = 16, for example, the
> ERR_CNT element is five bits wide

Could someone explain me the example. 'If n-k = 16, for example, the ERR_CNT element is five bits wide'.

I thought it will be 8=(n-k)/2

EDIT 1: In the example n-k =16, then the number of errors ( error correction capability) is (n-k)/2 or I can compute it as 2*e+E<=(n-k), where e - errors, E- erasures

Comment: I don't understand where your 8(n-k)/2 comes from? Could you explain why you think that would be the case?

Comment: @MarcusMüller i have edited and added some information

Comment: By the way, you linked to the encoder, not the decoder documentation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller fixed

Comment: I doubt very much that the Reed-Solomon decoder can fix _punctures_ (which are generally defined as _non-transmission_ of selected parity check symbols resulting in a received codeword of length $<n$), and it is worth noting that there is no rule that requires the number of erasures to be no more than $n-k$; the demodulator may well decide that more symbols than $n-k$ symbols are best sent to the decoder as erasures. So, `ERR_CNT` most likely contains the sum of the number of errors and number of erasures after a _successful decoding_ (which, with high probability, is a _correct decoding_).

Answer (score 1):

$\left\lfloor\frac{n-k}2\right\rfloor$ is the *maximum* number of bit errors that we can *guarantee* a code can correct for a binary channel.

But that doesn't mean a code can't sometimes correct more! (In general: not all code words have a distance that's equal to the code's minimum distance. It is the case for minimum distance separable codes, like RS codes are, though.)

Then:

RS codes are also used in applications where erasures, not bit flips, happen. You'll find the decoder documentation contains a section on erasure decoding.

You'll also find that a RS code can correct up to $n-k$ erasures – and my guess is that they made the count of that and the count of corrected errors the same width for design consistency reasons, and maybe to make different decoder IP interchangeable.

Note that giving a unsigned number more bits than it needs has no functional or FPGA utilization downside in IP cores: if whatever takes the output uses less bits than it has, the synthesizer will optimize away all calculations resulting in the bits that weren't used.